# Aligning Vertically Spaced Equations

Tags: equations, amsmath, mathtools

This question is most likely a duplicate and trivial, but I ask nonetheless as it is causing frustration. I have written the following

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\alpha_{a}\alpha_{b}+\alpha_{b} \alpha_{a}=\{\alpha_{a},\alpha_{b}\}=2\delta_{ab}\boldsymbol{1_{N}}, \: a,b=1,2,3, \\
\{\alpha_{a},\beta\}=\boldsymbol{0}, \: a=1,2,3, \\
\beta^{2}=\boldsymbol{1_{N}}, \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and am using `mathools` package. I am using the `equation` environment to keep the equations numbered. I'd like to keep the three equations above grouped under one number, but split onto separate lines. The problem that I run into is the alignment of the equations, namely [image]

aligns to the right. I'd like for the equations to align to the left, but have not been able to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place an ampersand (`&`) at the point where you would like the equations to align.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\alpha_{a}\alpha_{b}+\alpha_{b} \alpha_{a}=\{\alpha_{a},\alpha_{b}\}=2\delta_{ab}\boldsymbol{1_{N}}, \: a,b=1,2,3, \\
&\{\alpha_{a},\beta\}=\boldsymbol{0}, \: a=1,2,3, \\
&\beta^{2}=\boldsymbol{1_{N}}, \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]